# How to use ":template"-type strings in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

Both rails routes and whenever and a few other things I can't remember have a user-specified template string like so:

```
template_str = "I am going to :place at :time"
```

And then there's some magic function which embeds data in place of `:place` and `:time`, like so:

```
template_str.magic_embed_function(place: 'bed', time: '10 pm') 
#=> "I am going to bed at 10 pm"
```

How can I do this in my ruby projects? Is there a gem that implements `String#magic_embed_function`?

Comment: What's wrong with interpolation or printf?

Comment: @CodeGnome Ask Rails! This is meant to be used for multiple values, so that a user could specify "I am going to :place" and a gem or similar can crank out "I am going to work", "I am going to Seattle", "I am going to a black whole". As for printf, it doesn't work with mulitple strings since the order is unknown, the template could be "I am going to %s at %s" or it could be "At %s I will go to %s", and a gem implementing this would not be able to deal with both of those. Also, "I am going to :place" is much clearer IMO.

Comment: For the record, it's called a "black hole". A "black whole" is something very different which may or may not exist. Aside from that, nice question!

Comment: @QPaysTaxes $#@%! I thought I was done making that mistake in fourth grade... I can't even edit the comment now.

Comment: Yeah my timing was a little off. I was originally planning to post this seconds after the edit window closed. (no I wasn't, I stumbled on this question right when I posted that)

Comment: You can define a variables here it's instance as you need to call in template `@place, @time = 'bed',  '10 pm'` and iterate variable value in string like `template_str = "I am going to #{@place} at #{@time}"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Use Percent-Style Interpolation

There is a special type of interpolation that uses the [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) method. This allows you to interpolate ordinal ([Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html)) and non-ordinal ([Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html)) inputs into a format string similar to that provided by [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf). However, the use of a hash argument with this method enables support for named variables in the format string. As a minimalist example:

```
"%{foo} %{bar}" % {foo: 'baz', bar: 'quux'}
#=> "baz quux"
```

With a hash argument, the format-string placeholders are treated as hash keys to be replaced by the associated values in your hash. This makes the order of the variables passed in unimportant. Based on the code in your original post, you could use it as follows:

```
template_str = 'I am going to %{place} at %{time}.'
template_str % {time: '10:00 PM', place: 'bed'}
#=> "I am going to bed at 10:00 PM."
```

This is a useful technique when you want to pass an array or hash for interpolation, but may or may not offer advantages over other types of interpolation in the general case. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: That seems like a really good way of doing it -- why doesn't anything do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

I extended String class with a magic_embed_function as you asked..rs
It's very simple, first we split our string and collect the words and check if matches with this simple regex for symbols, basically says "if something starts with : , that's a symbol", after we found a symbol we replace using gsub! (global substitution, with the bang to change our object) passing our symbol as first param and the param received that corresponds to that symbol and at the end we return self, to return the string that called the method.

```
template_str = "I am goind to :place at :time"

class String
    def magic_embed_function(params)
        self.split(" ").collect do |value|
            if value =~ /:.*/
                self.gsub! value, params[value[1..value.length].to_sym]
            end
        end
        self
    end
end

p template_str.magic_embed_function({place: "bed", time: "10 pm"})

#"I am goind to bed at 10 pm"
```